# Custom map/regions on mouse over

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

I'm looking to create a map like this one with mouseovers on the different regions.

http://www.visitcalifornia.com/Explore/

What would be the easiest way to do this with Javascript (and/or google maps).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom overlays. Here is the link to the documentation and some examples.
[custom overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays)